# How to load videos from assets folder? (to play them with VideoView)

Tags: android, mp4, assets

I need to open a mp4 video from the assets folder and play it with VideoView.

I tryed with these two options, but none of them works....

```
mVideoView.setVideoPath("file:///android_asset/videos.mp4");
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.start();
```

and...

```
String uriPath = "file:///android_asset/videos.mp4";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.start();
```

These options didn't works, but if I try to open the video from the SDCARD it works perfectly, then, the problem is when I'm trying to load the video from the assets folder.

What I'm doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I don't know how to load videos from the assets folder. But I know how to load them from the /res/raw/ folder:

```
String uriPath = "android.resource://yourapplicationpackage/raw/videofilenamewithoutextension";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
video.setVideoURI(uri);
```

Comment: im not using a raw folder, im using assets

Comment: Just change the **raw** part to ** assets** .... late, but can b helpful for someone who's viewing it now

Comment: Hello,I have used VideoView to play video from raw folder, but video is not played in lower version below 2.3. It shows me error "Video cannot be played" please guide me where is the problem,as video plays in other versions.

Comment: @NidhiGondhia try this:
String uriPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.my_video_file;

Comment: is package name given as com.abc.xyz or something like com/abc/xyz?

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried `android.resource://${packageName}/assets/videoname`

Answer (score 30):

#### Playing the .mp4 file from `\assets` is not possible, you must load it from `\raw` folder.

Example:

if you have a file called `video.mp4` inside the `/raw` folder:

```
String fileName = "android.resource://"+  getPackageName() + "/raw/video";
VideoView vv = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.surface);
vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName));
vv.start();
```

Comment: After hours spent to search around this was the only answer that solve my issue!! Thank u a lot!

Comment: The question is about `assets`. Not `raw`.

Comment: It is not possible so I give another option.

Comment: it's possible ! just gave asset:///youvideo.mp4

Answer (score 6):

**EDITED**

Try:

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.videoview);        
mVideoView = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.surface_view);        
SurfaceHolder holder = mVideoView.getHolder();
holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDisplay(holder);        
AssetFileDescriptor afd;
try {
    afd = getAssets().openFd("v.mp4");        
    player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
    player.prepareAsync();
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

     @Override
     public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
     }
  });

} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: i'm not using MediaController, because i need to hide the controls of videoview.... then i dont know how to assign a filedescriptor to a videoView object.

Comment: also.... The method setDataSource(FileDescriptor, long, long) is undefined for the type MediaController

Comment: When you first asked the question there was `MediaController`. Now I'm confused what your code actually is like

Comment: I tryed with MC now and... The method setDataSource(FileDescriptor, long, long) is undefined for the type MediaController

Comment: I'm trying to make work your code but i can't, i dont understand how to fid your code with my code.... i dont know what i am doing wrong. I edited my question, check it.

Comment: Try to replace `mVideoView.start();` with `player.start();`

Comment: if i changue that line i got this error: ERROR/MediaPlayer(2878): start called in state 2

Comment: and: ERROR/MediaPlayer(2878): Error (-38,0)