# No response on full screen activity (different android version?)

Tags: android

Here is my code on full screen video.
It work just fine in emulator but not in real android phone.

```
public void videoClick(View view){
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),VideoFullscreenActivity.class);
    videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://tk.myessentialoils.ideasapp/raw/"+ contentStringList[count][2]);
    mIntent.putExtra("videoUri",videoUri);
    startActivity(mIntent);
}
```

My thinking is that the Uri problem.
Xiaomi android have different uri than other.
Some Huawei phone also not functioning well.

So is there any alternative to get the file instead?
Perhaps a work around that will work on all version of android.

Edit 1
as per Vivek Mishra suggestions,
tried the below

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),VideoFullscreenActivity.class);
    String path = "file:///android_asset/"+ contentStringList[count][2];
    videoUri = Uri.parse(path);
    mIntent.putExtra("videoUri",videoUri);
    startActivity(mIntent);
```

However i got this error >> Can't play this video
as per [How to load videos from assets folder? (to play them with VideoView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269353/how-to-load-videos-from-assets-folder-to-play-them-with-videoview) asset folder cannot play video

Edit 2
same question as Nullpointerexception, i cant get the Media player to work with my code.

```
Uri videoUri = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("videoUri");

    VideoView videoView=findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
    videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

    //videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.full));
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.start();
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    });
```

how do i implement the below code in my code above.

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd;
try {
afd = getAssets().openFd("v.mp4");        
player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(), 
afd.getLength());
player.prepareAsync();
player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

 @Override
 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
 }
 });

} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: Instead of raw put it in assets folder. I was trying the same thing yesterday but from raw folder it doesn't seem to work in huwaei devices. Also change your uri according to assets folder then.

Comment: Thank you Mishra, i will try this asset folder thing. 
Have you find a way that will work in all version of android?

Comment: SInce I was working on a demo project, so I didn't tried that hard

Comment: it's ok, thank you so much

Comment: @Vivek Mishra Can you take a look on the edit 1, what is wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269353/how-to-load-videos-from-assets-folder-to-play-them-with-videoview  
Cannot play video from assets folder

Comment: Did you tried the next answer with 5 upvotes in that link

Comment: @VivekMishra I cant make it to work, Can you show me?