# URI not functioning with xiaomi / huawei

Tags: android

So i have coded a few script that uses URI.
However there are a lot of complaints that the function not working in Xiaomi / Redmi / huawei. This coded are tested and work well within emulator.
[Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore/7265235#7265235)
[No response on full screen activity (different android version?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833631/no-response-on-full-screen-activity-different-android-version)

So any one have any suggestion /  work around for this problem?
Work around 1: To use assets folder(havent tried with picture, but mostly work-able, but not working with the video file.)

So far I narrow down my code to

```
videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + filename);
```

the above work only in emulator, not working in xiaomi / huawei
What can we do with this?

```
videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + R.raw.filename);
```

the above works well in both emulator and real phone.

Anyone had any thought on this?

Trying 1
[How to read file from res/raw by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912825/how-to-read-file-from-res-raw-by-name)

```
int videoID = getResources().getIdentifier("filename","raw", getPackageName());
videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + 
videoID);
```

Result: Working with emulators, still not working with my Redmi Note 2

Comment: Have you check my updated solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use path like this:

```
"android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.filename;
```

The file should be stored under **res/raw/filename** and it should be of **.mp4** type.

I have tested this on my Redmi note 3 and Redmi 3s prime phone.

**EDIT**

```
videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/"+"crop");
```

I have tested this on mentioned Redmi devices and it is working.

Comment: yes, R.raw.filename this work well in both, but what if i am using a string variable to open the file.Thus the 1st try come in, do you have any suggestion on how to overcome this?

Comment: make sure to enter **filename without extension**

Comment: also file name should not contain any special characters and underscore as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Yes, it work now!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)