# PlatformException(MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED, MEDIA_ELEMENT_ERROR: Format error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code for loading video from asset file:

```
class ChewiePlayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChewiePlayerWidgetState createState() => _ChewiePlayerWidgetState();
}

class _ChewiePlayerWidgetState extends State<ChewiePlayerWidget> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late ChewieController _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/images/IBT.mp4');
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _controller,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      
      // Placeholder image to display before the video loads
      placeholder: Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
      // Optional error message to display if the video fails to load
      errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            errorMessage,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        );
      },
      
    );
    
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Chewie(
      controller: _chewieController,
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

> PlatformException(MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED, MEDIA_ELEMENT_ERROR:
> Format error, The video has been found to be unsuitable (missing or in
> a format not supported by your browser)., null)`your text`

Comment: on what device you're testing?

Answer (score 0):

**It is not possible to play the.mp4 file from the assets folder; you must load it from the raw folder.**

**For Further Read This** :

[How to load videos from assets folder? (to play them with VideoView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269353/how-to-load-videos-from-assets-folder-to-play-them-with-videoview)